# Neo4j High Availablilty Seprate Write and Read in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, haproxy

I'm currently working on a project using spring data Neo4j 3.3.0 Remote, and Neo4j 2.1.7.

I'm planning on running this with a Neo4j cluster using 3 servers, I'm using HAProxy as the load balancer.

I want to optimize the cluster for read and writes, is there any way to separate read and writes on the application level?

For example, publish two front ends in HAProxy (one for master, and one for slaves) and have spring data decide which is appropriate,
or is there any better way to work with a cluster in Spring Data Neo4j Remote?

Comment: Right now there isn't. Something like that is planned for SDN4 though.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data for Neo4j till version 3.x are based on embedded Neo4j and support for server mode was added later.

Version 4.0 is written from scratch. Unfortunately it doesn't have support for optimization writes and reads in HA scenario.

It's on the roadmap and may be version 4.1 will support that.